# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "29-Oct-2018 00:01"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm using date format object:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatSearch = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
```

And try to parse a string:

```
Date dateForm = dateFormatSearch.parse("29-Oct-2018 00:01");
```

It shows me the following error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "29-Oct-2018 00:01"
```

Can anybody help? It seems to me I've got good pattern for such string.

Comment: Is your default `Locale` able to read `Oct` as a month abreviation ?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).